# Ionic Framework countdown when Pause

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am making a game that has a time limit.

In order to achieve that I made these **services.js** file:

```
var module=angular.module('starter.services', ['ionic', 'ui.router']);
module.factory('Game', function($interval)
{
      /**
      *Class we need for the game
      *@param items {Array} with the items the game consisted of
      *@param time {Int} How many seconds tis the duration of game
      *@param grid_width How many Items each row will have
      *@param grid_height How many items the grid will have vertically
      */
      function Game(items,time,grid_width,grid_height,callbacks,scope)
      {
        var game=this;

        //The total Items The game is consisted of
        game.items=items;

        //The grid of the items that will be swapped
        game.grid=[];

        game.callbacks=callbacks;

        game.scope=scope;

        /**
        *Function that performs the logic
        *and does the comparisons between Items
        */
        game.swap=function()
        {

        };

        /**
        *Method that Initialises and starts the game
        *Why I used this function and not game.start()
        *is because this way the code for initializing the grid is saparate from the code that initialises the clock
        */
        game.init=function()
        {
          game.timer=time;
          if(typeof game.callbacks === 'object' && typeof game.callbacks['afterInit'] === 'function') game.callbacks['afterInit'](game);
          game.play();
        }

        /*####################### Starting apausing and overing the game #############*/
        /**
        *The Game has the Foillowing Status
        *'uninitialised': When the game has Not Been Started yet
        *'play': When gameplay is on progress
        *'paused': When the game is paused
        *'over': When Game Over
        */
        game.status='uninitialised';


        game.timer=time;

        /**
        *Function that starts the timer
        */
        var startTimer=function()
        {
          if(game.timer>0)
          {
            //Better to Use Angular's Interval
            interval=$interval(function()
            {
              if(game.status==='play')
              {
                game.timer--;
                if(game.timer==0) game.over();

                if(typeof game.callbacks === 'object' && typeof game.callbacks['timerUpdate'] === 'function')
                {
                  game.callbacks['timerUpdate'](game.timer,game.scope);
                }
              }
            },1000);
          }
        }

        /**
        *Function that stops the timer
        */
        var stopTimer=function()
        {
          if(interval!==null) $interval.cancel(interval);
        }


        /**
        *The Interval of the setInterval();
        */
        var interval=null;

        /**
        *Method that Pauses the game
        *Enter here code that tell what will be executed when the game is paused
        */
        game.pause=function()
        {
          game.status='paused';
          if(typeof game.callbacks === 'object' && typeof game.callbacks['pause'] === 'function') game.callbacks['pause'](game.timer);
          //stopTimer();
        }


        /**
        *Method that starts the game
        *Enter code here to be executer when the game is started
        */
        game.play=function()
        {
          console.log("Game Started");
          game.status='play';

          //Start the counter
          startTimer();
        }

        /**
        *Method that ends the game
        *Enter code here to be executer when the game is ended
        */
        game.over=function()
        {
          game.status='over';
          if(interval!==null) $interval.cancel(interval);
        }

        game.isOver=function()
        {
          return game.status==='over';
        }

        game.isPaused=function()
        {
          return game.status==='paused';
        }

        game.isNotPausedOrOver=function()
        {
          return game.status==='play';
        }
        /*##############################################################################*/

        /*######################### For Scoring system #######################*/
        game.points=0;

        game.addScore=function(points)
        {
          game.points+=points;
        }

        game.removeScore=function(points)
        {
          game.points-=points;
        }
        /*#####################################################################*/

        /*########### Functions for Game Saving and Loading ###################*/
        game.save=function()
        {
          console.log("Game Saving");
          //Code for game saving
        }

        game.load=function()
        {
          //Code for game loading
        }
        /*########### End of Functions ddor Game saving and Loading ###########*/

      };//End Of Game Class

      /**
      *Function we need for the Game Item
      *@param icon {String} Normal Icon For the Item (it can be either html or image path)
      *@param icon_destroyed {String} Icon when The Game is Destroyed (it can be either html or image path)
      *@param icon_marked {String}
      */
      function GameItem(icon,icon_destroyed,icon_marked,name)
      {
        var item=this;

        item.icon=icon;//Icon for the normal situations
        item.icon_destroyed=icon_destroyed;//Icon if the item is Destroyed
        item.icon_marked=icon_marked;//Icon when the item is selected

        /*
        *A Characteristic name of the itemYourFactory
        *It can Be used for comparisons ;)
        */
        item.name=name;

        /**
        *For now takes 2 values:
        *start if the Item is not destroyed
        *destroyed if the item in destroyed
        *whatever dtatus you want
        */
        item.status="start";

        /**
        *The position of the Item
        *Check if you need it
        */
        item.posistion={x:0,y:0};

        /**
        *Check if this item is equal with another one
        */
        item.equals=function(other)
        {
          return other.name===item.name;
        };

        /**
        *Gets The icon regarding the status of the Item is
        */
        item.getIcon=function()
        {
          var icon="";
          //Add here the status of the
          switch(item.status)
          {
            case 'destroyed':
              icon=item.icon_destroyed;
            break;

            case 'start':
              icon=item.icon;
            break;

            default:
              icon=item.icon;
          }
          return icon;
        }
      };//End of Item Class

      return {
              game:Game,
              item:GameItem,
              current_game:null
             };
});
```

And I have made these controllers on file **controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','ui.router'])

/**
*Controller that does all the Dirty Job for the Game
*/
.controller('Game',function($scope,$timeout,$state,Game,MenuItem)
{

  /*################### Controller Initialization ####################*/
  var GameItem=Game.item;
  var GameClass=Game.game;
  /*##################### End Controller Initialization ##############*/

  /**
  *Function That does all the dirty job for initialization
  */
  var init_game=function()
  {
    console.log(Game.current_game);
    if(typeof Game.current_game === 'undefined' || Game.current_game === null)
    {
      /**
      *Items for the Game
      */
      var items=[
                  new GameItem('./img/icon1.png','./img/icon1.png','./img/icon1.png','trolley'),
                  new GameItem('./img/icon2.png','./img/icon2.png','./img/icon2.png','metro'),
                  new GameItem('./img/icon3.png','./img/icon3.png','./img/icon3.png','bus'),
                  new GameItem('./img/icon4.png','./img/icon4.png','./img/icon4.png','tram'),
                ];

      /**
      *Callbacks for Game
      */
      var callbacks={
                      'timerUpdate':function(time,scope)
                      {
                        $timeout(function()
                        {
                          $scope.time=time;
                          console.log($scope.time);
                        });
                      },
                      'pause':function(time)
                      {
                        console.log("Game Paused");
                        $state.go('menu');
                      },
                      'afterInit':function(game)
                      {
                        MenuItem.items.play.name_="Continue Game";
                        MenuItem.items.play.clickFunction=function()
                        {
                          console.log("clicked");
                          $state.go('game');
                          Game.current_game.play();//Do not comment unlsess game will not resume
                        };

                        /*Making An Option For saving*/
                        var saveItem=new MenuItem.MenuItem("Save Game",'regular-btn',"",false,function()
                        {
                          game.save();
                        });
                        //Add on the top an Option to save the game
                        MenuItem.items.others.unshift(saveItem);
                        console.log(MenuItem.items.others);
                      }
                    };

      Game.current_game=new GameClass(items,60,5,10,callbacks,$scope);
      Game.current_game.init();
    }
    else // We may need to go to another page and return Therefore we must need a way to resume
    {
      console.log("Here resuming the game");
      Game.current_game.play();
    }
  };


  init_game();

  $scope.pause=function()
  {
    console.log("Pausing Game");
    Game.current_game.pause();
  }
});
```

The problem now is that On my App there is a PAUSE button so when I click on it it pauses the timer. The prob is when I get Back from main menu even though the timeout continues to countdown it is like the $scope get never updated.

What I actualy do is:

1. From main menu go to game page. (At this step the timer is shown
   correctly)
2. Click on pause and go back to main menu.
3. From main menu I go back to game page. (And even though the timer counts down as I can see with console.log I cannot see on scope).

Note: The value of the timer is updated with angular's $interval() function.

You can see more details here:
[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tDgZ.png)

Also there is the full code here: https://github.com/pc-magas/faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging I found a solution to your problem. View wasn't updated since **$scope** inside **timerUpdate** callback was different than the one in Game controller. Actually, Angular should update scope automatically when timer's value is changed in the interval. You shouldn't use callback to achieve that. I present my solution below.

**Game factory**

1) Instead of saving seconds value in **timer** directly, save it as property of an object:

```
game.timer = {
    value: time
}
```

2) Remove code which executes **timerUpdate** callback from startTimer function. You won't need it.

```
if(typeof game.callbacks === 'object' && typeof game.callbacks['timerUpdate'] === 'function')
{
     game.callbacks['timerUpdate'](game.timer);          
}
```

3) Remove all controller scope references from your Game factory. Services should have no idea of controllers' scope existence.

**Game controller**

1) Remove **timerUpdate** function from callbacks. You won't need it anymore.

2) Instead of assigning new timer value to scope inside callback, create a scope property after game initialization:

```
init_game();
$scope.timer = Game.current_game.timer;
```

Now, **$scope.timer** contains a reference to your **timer** object. Once the timer's **value** gets updated, scope will register that and make proper changes to the view.

**Game view**

Last change you need to do is substitute `{{timer}}` with `{{timer.value}}` in the Game view.

---

***Two hints at the end***

1) Angular has many built-in functions, which make life easier. One of them is **angular.isFunction()** which checks if object is a function. You don't need a code like this:

```
typeof game.callbacks === 'object' && typeof game.callbacks['afterInit'] === 'function'
```

2) To check if object is **null** or **undefined**, you also don't need a code like the one you used:

```
if(typeof Game.current_game === 'undefined' || Game.current_game === null)
```

You can simply write:

```
if(!Game.current_game)
```

Comment: Thanks but how in your solution but I get the very same problem. When I go back to the game view the timer is not displayed. On Init I manage to get the timer but when I go back to the page I cannot get it.

Comment: I looked at your commit history and saw that you put $scpope.timer after Game.current_game.init() instead of execution of private init_game() function. However it doesn't matter now, because I see that you've resolved the problem already.